# Only copy cells with data from Excel to Word

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I need some further help developing my code. I have the basics down now with some earlier help but I am not sure on this next part.

The code I am designing will run in a spreadsheet whereby the amount of rows used in a sheet will vary depending on the amount of data being used. (Due to nature of business and Norwegian Laws, I can't go into more details.)

I'd like to have a Range of `B5:B1000` as a standard range and only have cells containing data be auto filled into the template but I am unsure how to write said code. Could someone please advise how I am able to go about this?

All questions related to this have been based on copying from one sheet to another.

This is my code so far which I am using in excel:

```
Sub CopyRangeToWord()
Dim objWord
Dim objDoc
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\CoffeeFuelsMeNow\Documents\Custom Office Templates\EVERYTHING IS AWESOME.dotx")

Range("B5:B92").Copy


With objDoc.Paragraphs(objDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range
   'All formatting goes here
   .PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
End With
objWord.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes that column **B** is *compact* (no holes in the data):

```
Sub CopyRangeToWord()
    Dim objWord, N As Long
    Dim objDoc
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.documents.Add

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("B5:B" & N).Copy


    With objDoc.Paragraphs(objDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range
       'All formatting goes here
       .PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
    End With
    objWord.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It's being used on a pivot table (not my design) but works either way :)

Comment: Ah, it's now ignoring my {.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)}

Comment: @CoffeeFuelsMeNow  I don't have access to your doc, so I can't debug what going on............sorry..............

Comment: @CoffeeFuelsMeNow You may need to **re-format after the paste**

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Thank you. I am completely new to this.